# query cloudkit with currentUserRecordId.recordName hash instead of "__defaultOwner__"

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckquery

When querying records that  current user created, the value in currentUserRecordID.recordName is "____defaultOwner__"

Is there a way to tell cloudKit to return the real hash key instead of "____defaultOwner____" ***in the results*** ?

I consider to replace "manually" the defaultOwner string with currentUserRecordID.recordName, but before doing that, I want to check maybe there is the "simple" way that cloudKit server will do this.